# How do i implement "ONVIF" protocol in "React-Native"?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, onvif

Please help me to find solution how to implement "Onvif" in React native.

I have tried "Onvif" library but didn't get any results.

Comment: Which exact library? what error message do you get? what code have you tried? You need to give us more about your problem to even attempt to help. read this for help in how to form a good question here => https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Remember Onvif is a standard.
https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmers_Guide-1.pdf#page6